# Compare two dataframes based on two numeric columns and find rows matching within a numeric threshold of eachother

Tags: python

I have two separate datasets that follow this structure:

```
import pandas as pd

data_one = {'ID':[281.1, 290.125, 450.123, 980.11,   1200,  130,  12,      500,   401.1,  1025.349], 
        'Code':  [201,   205.1,   900,     1200.54,  52,    44,   111.223, 192.1, 120.99, 11.1]} 

df_one = pd.DataFrame(data_one)
df_one
```

> ```
>   ID        Code
> 0 281.100   201.000
> 1 290.125   205.100
> 2 450.123   900.000
> 3 980.110   1200.540
> 4 1200.000  52.000
> 5 130.000   44.000
> 6 12.000    111.223
> 7 500.000   192.100
> 8 401.100   120.990
> 9 1025.349  11.100
> ```

```
data_two = {'ID':[405.122, 12.125, 11356.12, 85.111,    1025.4069,   112.1111,  2112,      1200.6582,   980.1035,     441.123,  52842.584, 5648.12, 11], 
        'Code':  [1000,    33.1,   222,      101.541,   26.75,       25.2564,   11.08,     192.1,       1220.1258,    11.1,     7894,      1323,    123.123]}

df_two = pd.DataFrame(data_two) 
df_two
```

> ```
>       ID          Code
> 0     405.1220    1000.0000
> 1     12.1250     33.1000
> 2     11356.1200  222.0000
> 3     85.1110     101.5410
> 4     1025.4069   26.7500
> 5     112.1111    25.2564
> 6     2112.0000   11.0800
> 7     1200.6582   192.1000
> 8     980.1035    1220.1258
> 9     441.1230    11.1000
> 10    52842.5840  7894.0000
> 11    5648.1200   1323.0000
> 12    11.0000     123.1230
> ```

I want to find rows between these two dataframes where ID and Code are in agreement but within a certain numeric threshold of `±0.5` for `ID` and `±30` for `Code`, respectively.

So a match is returned when for particular row:

```
df_one.ID is in this range: [df_two.ID-0.5,df_two.ID+0.5] AND df_one.Code is in the range [df_two.Code-30,df_two.code+30]
```

For example, row 3 from df_one matches with row 8 from df_two because ID and Code both satisfy the conditions.

```
            ID.1      Code.1       ID.2        Code.2
match_1     980.110   1200.540     980.1035    1220.1258
```

Another match is:

```
            ID.1      Code.1       ID.2        Code.2
match_2     1025.349  11.100       1025.4069   26.7500
```

Comment: can total matches be a dataframe?

Comment: @PrakashDahal Yes. I don't really mind what the final structure of the data is. It could be a dataframe, csv file, or a dictionary. What I am interested in is just seeing if there are any matches at all and to be able to see easily what those matches are. So the original ID and Code from both dataframes should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a brute force way but will always find your desired solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df3 = pd.DataFrame({}, columns=['ID.1', 'Code.1', 'ID.2', 'Code.2'])
id_1 = []
id_2 = []
code_1 = []
code_2 = []
for i, a in enumerate(list(df_one['ID'].values)):
  for i2, a2 in enumerate(list(df_two['ID'].values)):
    if ((((df_one.iloc[i, 0]) >= (df_two.iloc[i2, 0] - 0.5)) and  ((df_one.iloc[i, 0]) <= (df_two.iloc[i2, 0] + 0.5))) and 
        (((df_one.iloc[i, 1]) >= (df_two.iloc[i2, 1] - 30)) and ((df_one.iloc[i, 1]) <= (df_two.iloc[i2, 1] + 30)))):
      id_1.append(df_one.iloc[i, 0])
      id_2.append(df_two.iloc[i2, 0])
      code_1.append(df_one.iloc[i, 1])
      code_2.append(df_two.iloc[i2, 1])

df3['ID.1'] = id_1
df3['Code.1'] = code_1
df3['ID.2'] = id_2
df3['Code.2'] = code_2
df3
```